# Radiobuttons with the same name React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a radiobutton component, and it's causing me some headaches.

This is my code:

```
class RadioButton extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: '' };
  }
  handleRadioButtonChange = event =>
    this.setState({ selected: event.target.value });
  render() {
    const { disabled, label, name, value } = this.props;
    const { selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <StyledLabel>
        <RadioButtonComponent
          id={value}
          name={name}
          value={value}
          checked={selected === value}
          disabled={disabled}
          onChange={this.handleRadioButtonChange}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </StyledLabel>
    );
  }
}
```

RadioButtonComponent is something I use to style the radiobutton the way I want.

```
const RadioButtonComponent = ({ checked, ...props }) => (
  <RadioButtonContainer>
    <HiddenRadioButton checked={checked} {...props} />
    <StyledRadioButton checked={checked}>
      <Icon viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <circle />
      </Icon>
    </StyledRadioButton>
  </RadioButtonContainer>
);
```

The HiddenRadioButton is the input with style "radio" and it's hidden with the hideVisually function from the polished library. The StyledRadioButton is a styled components div that is styled to make it look the way I want.

It works to the level that they are displayed, can be clicked and they toggle on. Obviously they can't be toggled off. But when I create say 2 checkboxes with the same name:

```
<RadioButton value="1" name="group" />
<RadioButton value="2" name="group" />
```

I can select both. I would expect one to switch off and the other on.

When I change RadioButtonComponent to input type="radio" it works, but doesn't look the way I want. Also, it seems like I have to click it twice to select it.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**EDIT:**
If I unhide the html checkbox, it does toggle. But StyledRadioButton doesn't get the right 'checked' state?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j5zorwr3v

Comment: Might be worth trying to recreate at https://codesandbox.io/, I can take a look there. You're close, though. As a sidenote, 4 components for a single elements seems like a lot to me, but I guess it depends upon exactly what each component is responsible for.

Comment: @Toby Thanks, I've created a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j5zorwr3v

Comment: @Toby Have you had the chance to take a look?

Comment: Apologies, I was struggling to follow all the code you posted - I'm not clear why you have so many components to achieve this - I've added an answer with a working demo that I believe you should be able to start with, and add back in your styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you have four components in order to achieve this, but I see one area causing unnecessary complication - you are trying to implement radio buttons as individual components, when actually radio buttons are more akin to select drop down menus. You would have multiple values, but only one is "selected", and only one value is stored in state.

You could break out each radio to it's own component, but then you'd have to manage selected state across multiple components, and I believe this is where you could optimize your code. See this Code Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/9jjwwzwoxw

This is the simplest working example I could come up with. Note that we provide the various values to the single component, then map over the values to create each radio button.

Also note that you can apply your style customizations to a component within the map, which is different than trying to manage selected state across multiple radio components.

**Edit:** I've added an example of how to add a className and CSS styling within each radio to determine which elements is checked.